# Exotic bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Clearly there is no continuous bijections $f,g~:~\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $fg$ is a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

If we omit the continuity assumption, is there such an example ?

Notes: to follow from Dustan's comments:
Notes:  By definition $fg~:~x \mapsto f(x)\times g(x)$ and not $f\circ g$.
If there were continuous bijections just look at the limits of $f$ and $g$ at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ to conclude that $fg$ can't be a bijection

Comment: What if $f=g=1_\mathbb{R}$ (the identity map)...?

Comment: Ah, sorry, does $fg$ mean multiplication? I read it as composition

Comment: You are receiving close votes on this question. I'd recommend two things: 1. Make it clear, per Robert's comments, that you are referring to multiplication of functions, not composition. 2. To add some more context, explain what makes you say your first remark is clear. It took me a while to come up with a proof myself, though that might just be because I haven't thought about this kind of thing in a while.

Comment: Perhaps try it with a smaller set, say, $\mathbb Z$, first? Perhaps it can give you an idea. (Note: I have not tried this yet.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x$, and define $g$ piecewise by
$$
  g(x) =
  \begin{cases} 
    -x ,& x \in \cdots \cup (-16,-8] \cup (-4,-2] \cup \cdots
        &= \bigcup_k -[2 \cdot 4^k, 4 \cdot 4^k) \\
    4x ,& x \in \cdots \cup (-8,-4] \cup (-2,-1] \cup \cdots
        &= \bigcup_k -[4^k, 2 \cdot 4^k) \\
    0 ,& x = 0 \\
    x ,& x \in \cdots \cup [1,2) \cup [4,8) \cup \cdots
        &= \bigcup_k [4^k, 2 \cdot 4^k) \\
    -\frac14 x ,& x \in \cdots \cup [2,4) \cup [8,16) \cup \cdots
        &= \bigcup_k [2 \cdot 4^k, 4 \cdot 4^k) \\
   \end{cases}
$$
(where $-[b,a)$ just means $(-a,-b]$).

This $g$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, since

- $g$ maps $\bigcup_k -[2 \cdot 4^k, 4 \cdot 4^k)$ one-to-one onto $\bigcup_k [2 \cdot 4^k, 4 \cdot 4^k)$.
- $g$ maps $\bigcup_k [2 \cdot 4^k, 4 \cdot 4^k)$ one-to-one onto $\bigcup_k -[2 \cdot 4^k, 4 \cdot 4^k)$.
- $g$ maps $\bigcup_k -[4^k, 2 \cdot 4^k)$ one-to-one onto itself.
- $g$ maps $\bigcup_k [4^k, 2 \cdot 4^k)$ one-to-one onto itself.
- $g$ maps $0$ to itself.

And $fg$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, since

- $fg$ maps $\bigcup_k -[2 \cdot 4^k, 4 \cdot 4^k)$ one-to-one onto $\bigcup_k -[4 \cdot 16^k, 16 \cdot 16^k)$.
- $fg$ maps $\bigcup_k [2 \cdot 4^k, 4 \cdot 4^k)$ one-to-one onto $\bigcup_k -[16^k, 4 \cdot 16^k)$.
- $fg$ maps $\bigcup_k -[4^k, 2 \cdot 4^k)$ one-to-one onto $\bigcup_k [4 \cdot 16^k, 16 \cdot 16^k)$.
- $fg$ maps $\bigcup_k [4^k, 2 \cdot 4^k)$ one-to-one onto $\bigcup_k [16^k, 4 \cdot 16^k)$.
- $fg$ maps $0$ to itself.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to set $-(b,a]=[-a,-b)$, not $-[b,a)=[-a,-b)$? I'm assuming that you mean the notation in the sense of applying the $x\mapsto -x$ function to each element of the set, as in $2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I meant to write $-[b,a) = (-a,-b]$ (where the notation is meant to suggest applying $x \mapsto -x$ to the set, as you said). It's now fixed.

Comment: To cover the domain/range of $\pm(0,1)$, I assume $-\infty<k<+\infty$.

Comment: @MarkHurd yes that's correct.

Answer (score 4):

With the axiom of choice we can prove a much more general result:

**Theorem.** If $X$ is an infinite group (or field), then there are bijections $f,g:X\to X$ such that $f(x)g(x)=x$ for all $x\in X$.

**Proof.** It will suffice to prove it for a group; if $X$ is an infinite field, we can apply the theorem to the multiplicative group $X\setminus\{0\}$ and then extend the bijections to $X$ by setting $f(0)=g(0)=0$. Moreover, it will suffice to construct three bijections $f,g,h:X\to X$ such that $f(x)g(x)=h(x)$ for all $x\in X$; then $f\circ h^{-1}$ and $g\circ h^{-1}$ will be bijections whose product is the identity map.

Let $X$ be an infinite group, $|X|=\kappa$, and choose a well-ordering $\prec$ of $X$ such that $|\{y\in X:y\prec x\}|\lt\kappa$ for each $x\in X$. Partition $X$ into disjoint sets $A,B,C$ with $|A|=|B|=|C|=\kappa$. We define $f,g,h:X\to X$ by transfinite induction. Consider $x\in X$, and suppose $f(y),g(y),h(y)$ have been defined for all $y\prec x$; we define $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ as follows.

If $x\in A$, let $f(x)$ be the least element of $X\setminus\{f(y):y\prec x\}$; then choose $g(x)\in X\setminus\bigcup_{y\prec x}\{g(y),\ f^{-1}(x)h(y)\}$ and let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$.

If $x\in B$, let $g(x)$ be the least element of $X\setminus\{g(y):y\prec x\}$; then choose $f(x)\in X\setminus\bigcup_{y\prec x}\{f(y),\ h(y)g(x)^{-1}\}$ and let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$.

If $x\in C$, let $h(x)$ be the least element of $X\setminus\{h(y):y\prec x\}$; then choose $f(x)\in X\setminus\bigcup_{y\prec x}\{f(y),\ h(x)g(y)^{-1}\}$ and let $g(x)=f(x)^{-1}h(x)$.

Now we have bijections $f,g,h:X\to X$ such that $f(x)g(x)=h(x)$ for all $x\in X$. (Injectivity is clear from the definition; surjectivity can be proved by transfinite induction.)

Comment: I would rephrase the theorem statement to hold for any well-ordered group $X$ since you don't seem to need choice except in the well-ordering at the beginning. (It is easy to modify a given well-ordering to get a well-ordering whose order type is a cardinal.)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Good point. In particular, the proof for countably infinite groups is constructive.